# How to marshal a C++ enum in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I need to create a wrapper between C++ and C#. I have a function very similar to this:

```
virtual SOMEINTERFACE* MethodName(ATTRIBUTE_TYPE attribType = ATTRIBUTE_TYPE::ATTRIB_STANDARD) = 0;
```

The `enum` is declared like this:

```
enum class ATTRIBUTE_TYPE { 
    ATTRIB_STANDARD, 
    ATTRIB_LENGTH 
};
```

How do I wrap that ATTRIBUTE_TYPE enum?

Comment: What is the underlying type for `ATTRIBUTE_TYPE`?

Comment: Just a simple enum:  enum class ATTRIBUTE_TYPE
{
   ATTRIB_STANDARD,
   ATTRIB_LENGTH
};

Comment: insofar as you specify the type on the enum in C# and C++ (and they are the same) you should be able to use the enum directly in the P/Invoke. Just be forewarned that not all the C++ and C# types that share names are the same, e.g. `long` in C# is an int64 whereas in C++ it's just an int32.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5584160/332733

Comment: @Mgetz <pedantic>The 'long' type is 32-bits in Microsoft C++; it follows the architecture size most elsewhere (ex. GCC).</pedantic>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your C++ enum is defined like this:

```
enum class ATTRIBUTE_TYPE { 
    ATTRIB_STANDARD, 
    ATTRIB_LENGTH 
};
```

By default, `enum class` types are `int` sized. Which means that you can translate this to C# like so:

```
enum ATTRIBUTE_TYPE { 
    ATTRIB_STANDARD, 
    ATTRIB_LENGTH 
};
```

That's all there is to it. A C# enum is blittable and this C# enum maps exactly on to your C++ enum.